# Django - Automatic User Deactivation after session

Tags: python, django, validation

In my User Model, I have set the following fields:

```
is_deactivated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
deactivation_initiated = models.DateTimeField(null=True) 
deactivate_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Whenever any User interacts with anything on the App (clicking a button, refreshing a page, etc.), I would like to check whether `is_deactivated` is `True`. If it is `True`, then I would like to compare the current real-world time with the `deactivate_at` time.

If the `deactivate_at` time has passed. Then I would like to automatically log the user out, and set `is_active=False` for the user.

I am unsure of how to implement something like this.

Comment: Rather than using the `User` model, I would suggest using [django session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry).

Comment: Also you can use middleware

Comment: Hi, thank you for your responses. Could you please elaborate on how I could use Django session to solve my problem? I would like to make a user account inactive once their deactivate_at time has been reached.